# using wget to fill in a webpage form

Tags: wget

I am trying to use `wget` to download the last 100 game history for [keno from the MO lottery website](http://www.molottery.com/numbers/check_clubKeno_tickets.jsp).

Sample range -> 1420698-1420797

The webpage requires entering a range and then clicking a button.  I am trying to automate the process but not having much success. Below is a list
of the values that I have dug out of the page linked above.

```
<form name="winnersForm">
  <input type="text" name="drawnumber" size="8" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Display Winning Number" onClick="window.open('../club_keno/club_keno_drawings.html')/>
```

I am not sure wget can do this sort of thing as it may require some java code
such as a session ID number.  I have tried parsing everything into a single string then use the shell command to run it but get nothing but the main page in my download, no numbers.  I have read the manual and searched for examples but can't seem to find anything for what I am trying to do. I wrote a program that will strip all the tags and format the data into a text file which I use for other games.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: stackexchagnes sites mess up code unless it's in code tags.. i'd improve it but it seems there's an edit that is forever in pending,  your post's poor formatting is a stackexchange issue really

Comment: also did you not even use angle brackets with that form code you wrote , I don't think stackexchange sites eat them too, if so, then that's very poor formatting on your part too.. not even formatting but your code itself you are meant to write it properly.

Comment: you also haven't specified whether the form method is get or post, i guess get which is default. This may help.   https://philihp.com/blog/2008/using-wget-with-http-get-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't really seem to do any checking or session validation and I'm able to get all the numbers.

From your browser, `copy as cURL` (see [here](http://lornajane.net/posts/2013/chrome-feature-copy-as-curl)). Remove extraneous headers and add filtering.

I ended up with:

```
curl 'http://www.molottery.com/gameHistory.do?method=ckDisplay&cmt=true' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' --data 'drawnumber=1420698-1420797' --compressed | grep td
```

which results in:

```
                    --------
                    -----------
                 <td align="center">52</td><td align="center">44</td><td align="center">10 - 14 - 20 - 21 - 24 - 27 - 28 - 32 - 33 - 39 -
                            41 - 42 - 44 - 45 - 46 - 48 - 52 - 57 - 58 - 72</td>
                            <td align="center">1</td>
                            <td align="center"> $1,077</td><td align="center"> $5,966</td><td align="center"> $15,210</td></tr>
                    <td>1420789</td>
                    <td>07-06-16</td>
                    --------
                    -----
```

Now all your script needs to do is update `drawnumber` in the request.

I haven't tried with wget, but the process should work fine.